# difference between methods of query

Tags: wp-query, query

Looking in other plugins/widgets code , I usually see TWO different methods for a query :

one would be :

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $limit , // or, 1, or 20 ...
                'exclude' => '1049',
                'meta_key' => 'some_meta',
                'post_status'=>'publish');
$recent_posts = get_posts( $args ); //or get_recent_posts() or any other function
//end query
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ // do something with array
$pop_string .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'>' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a></li> ';
}
echo $pop_string;
```

the second method would be :

```
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
// query posts
$my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&meta_key=somekey&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=somevalue&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC');
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();
$pop_string .= '<li><a href="' . the_permalink() . '" rel="upcomming" title="' . the_title() . '">';
$pospstring .=  the_title() . '</a></li>';
}
}

echo $pop_string;
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
```

I am very curious as to What is the difference between them .

(I do not mean the fact that one uses array and one is using direct wp functions. - but more the technical capabilities)
I understand that the second one is a "custom loop" and the first one is "outside" a loop - but both can be used in widgets for example, to achieve very similar results (if not equal ..)

1. Is there something that one can do , that the other can´t ?
2. Which one is the preferred choice , and when ?
3. what would be the considerations to use one over the other , and how
   to choose them?
4. Is there a performance difference ?
5. If I want for example to write some simple widgets to get data -
   which should I choose ? and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query` that sets the `$wp_query` global.

Comment: so that means they are actually equal ? no difference as to what to use when or what is "best practice" ?

Comment: If you look on line 90 of `wp-includes/query.php`, you can see that `query_posts()` is just a 3 line function that executes a `WP_Query`. The difference is that it will automatically setup `have_posts()` and `the_post()` (as well as all associated functions), whereas `WP_Query` will need a specific object, ie: `$my_query->have_posts()`, in the declaration of the loop.

Comment: ok .. Thanks for the Uber-quick answer !